# Camel: changing stream encoding

Tags: apache-camel

I'm receiving data stream from http with that route:

```
from("direct:foo").
to("http://foo.com/bar.html").
to("file:///tmp/bar.html")
```

HTTP stream comes with `Windows-1251` encoding. I'd like to re-code to `UTF-8` on the fly and then store to file.

How to do that using standard `camel` way?

Comment: Have you tried `convertBodyTo`? http://camel.apache.org/convertbodyto.html

Comment: `convertBodyTo()` converts the `type` of body, not encoding

Comment: Found that it accepts encoding. Thanks. Trying now.

Comment: Hm. I would imagine that you have to convert the stream to a string first, using CP1251 with `convertBodyTo()`. Then convert that string to UTF-8 by setting the `charset` parameter on the file endpoint URL.

Comment: Please, convert your suggestiong to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at `.convertBodyTo()` - in particular the `charset` argument.

```
from("direct:foo").
to("http://foo.com/bar.html").
convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
to("file:///tmp/bar.html")
```

Reference: http://camel.apache.org/convertbodyto.html

Answer (score 9):

I think vikingsteve's solution misses a step. The input stream contains characters with encoding CP1251. The characters in that stream will not change their encoding when you convert the input stream contents to a string. You need to specify the same character encoding scheme that was used by the entity that encoded the characters when you decode them. Otherwise you will get undesirable results.

```xml
<route id="process_umlaug_file" startupOrder="2">
    <from uri="file:///home/steppra1/Downloads?fileName=input_umlauts.txt"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <to uri="file:///home/steppra1/Downloads?fileName=output_umlauts.txt&amp;charset=UTF-8"/>
</route>
```

I tested this reading a CP1251 encoded file containing German umlauts:

```
steppra1@steppra1-linux-mint ~/Downloads $ file input_umlauts.txt 
input_umlauts.txt: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators

steppra1@steppra1-linux-mint ~/Downloads $ file output_umlauts.txt 
output_umlauts.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Using the two steps of decoding and then re-coding yields properly encoded German umlauts. If I change above route to

```xml
<route id="process_umlaug_file" startupOrder="2">
    <from uri="file:///home/steppra1/Downloads?fileName=input_umlauts.txt"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <to uri="file:///home/steppra1/Downloads?fileName=output_umlauts.txt"/>
</route>
```

then the output file is still UTF-8 encoded, possibly because that is my platform default, but the umlauts are garbled.