# Norwegian Characters shown incorrectly in response

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-camel

We are using camel http to call third party services. As part of response we are getting some Norwegian characters in response. But those characters are changing to some other format as below.

**på** to **pÃ¥**

**Besøk i** kullgruve 3 (morgentur) to **BesÃ¸k i** kullgruve 3 (morgentur)

My camel route is as follow

```
from uri="direct:http" />
                     <to uri="http://test.com" />
                     <camel:removeHeader headerName="logMessage" />
                     <transform>
                           <simple>${bodyAs(String)}</simple>
                     </transform>
```

can some please suggest how can i get the same characters without alter?

Comment: Seems to be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570081/camel-changing-stream-encoding

Comment: @lazyneuron the suggestion in the post i tried before posting question but none of them worked for me.file to file reading is working. But in my case the response from http component itself modified the special characters.Please suggest any other way to solve to this issue as i am stuck at this point.